# how can I redirect in .jsp while working with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am developing application using Ajax and jsp.

My index.jsp page has HTML code for Login and some Ajax code in javascript. Ajax will call my another CheckLogin.jsp page

CheckLogin.jsp page checks on server for valid username and password. It returns "success" if it's valid otherwise will return message stating "username or password is not valid."

Now, when username and passwrod is valid, instead of success, I want to redirect the page to "Home.jsp" what should I do?

I am new to jsp. I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP code gets run once on the server before it goes to the client, so JSP/JSTL cannot do a redirect following the success or otherwise of an AJAX call (without a full page refresh - which obviates the use of AJAX). You should to do the redirect with Javascript:

```
if (success) {
    var successUrl = "Home.jsp"; // might be a good idea to return this URL in the successful AJAX call
    window.location.href = successUrl;
}
```

On successful AJAX call/validation, the browser window will reload with the new URL (effectively a redirect).

Comment: what is success in "if (success)"? because I tried one way like my jsp page will return message "success" and I was trying to check in my index page if that response message is success than redirect the page but that message contains some extra charater and also was not sure datatype of response message so do not able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks nickdos. I did string comparision at if statement. used the same idea mentioned in above comment. I was making mistake in string comparision and use of trim function. I made mistake between javascript and java. but ur window.location.href = successUrl worked fine

Comment: One can also use document.location = successUrl

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see your code, you can integrate this somewhere inside your validation :

```
<%
    pageContext.forward("logged.jsp");
%>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is giving me code of my Home.jsp(here in your example logged.jsp). and I am displaying the response coming from my checklogin.jsp file into one <div>. it is displaying that Home.jsp code into the that <DIV> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
function Edit() {
var allVals = $('#NEWFORMCampaignID').val();
if (allVals > 0) {
  window.location = '/SMS/PrepareSMS?id='+allVals;
}
else
  alert("Invalid campaign to Edit")
```

}

In order to redirect using Button click and pass some parameters, you can call the Controller Path(@RequestMapping(value="/SMS/PrepareSMS")) and then handle it there..